# Java Design Pattern for Service to apply method over object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am looking for a design pattern which will allow my service to process the BufferedImage and than store it to different databases and returns something other object. Is it possible to do so ?

```
Object processed = imageService.process(bufferedImage)
                .resize(width, height)
                .crop()
                .removeTransparency()
                .saveToDB_A()
                .saveToDB_B()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is that of [Fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) or, if you look at some angle, a `Builder` pattern.

Comment: Still, allowing the ImageService to save that image to a DB would break Single Responsibility Principle. Since we're talking about patterns (best practices involved) it would be better to make the ImageService have a ``.invoke(Consumer<BufferedImage> function)`` method to simply be able to invoke any function on the ``BufferedImage``. In this way you would be able to store the image without jeopardizing SRP in ImageService.